# Javascript to change class in <ul> tag not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

Based on the size of the window, I'm trying to alter the class of a  tag:

```
<ul id="navul" class="nav navbar-nav">
```

and making it instead be:

```
<ul id="navul" class="nav nav-pills">
```

This is what I am trying, and isn't working:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).resize(function () {
            $("count").text(x += 1);

            if ($window.width() < 768) {
                $('#navul')
                    .removeClass('navbar-nav')
                    .addClass('nav-pills');
            };
            if ($window.width() > 769) {
                $('#navul')
                    .removeClass('navbar-pills')
                    .addClass('nav-bar');
            };

        });
    });
</script>
```

I've also tried wrapping it inside

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ....
});
```

From watching DOM in dev tools, it would seem as if the script is not firing at all.  I'm probably missing something simple.

**EDIT:**

I used this as my starting template:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_resize

This script works perfectly *without* $(window) being declared.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
x = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $("span").text(x += 1);
    });
});
</script>

<p>Window resized <span>0</span> times.</p>
```

Comment: Have you declared $window anywhere?

Comment: See the edit to my original question.  If you follow the link, the sample script works.  And I can replicate that on my page.  The problem seems to be with swapping out the class.

Comment: Your edit does not address the fact that $window is an *undefined* variable.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.  You had to follow the link.  See the re-edit.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston no its $(window) not $window... to be specific you need brackets around window

Comment: Nakib - post that as an answer, and I'll mark it.  That nailed it.  Knew it was something silly and simple.

Comment: Exactly what @Nakib said (only it's parentheses, not brackets). The link you provided is totally and completely irrelevant because **there is an error in your code**. $window isn't a variable you've declared anywhere. Change all instances of `$window` to `$(window)`.

Comment: @tyler my bad  parentheses, not brackets :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing like $window and it will give you error and wont run the script change **$window.width()** to

```
$(window).width()
```

$window will give you error of undefined

Comment: See the edit to my original question. If you follow the link, the sample script works. And I can replicate that on my page. The problem seems to be with swapping out the class.

Comment: "If you follow the link, the sample script works." The link doesn't use $window.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston try some console logging

Comment: ok ok - it does indeed use $(window).  But it does NOT use $(window).width.

Comment: Yea you will require brackets around window else you will get error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your $window variable is undefined?
Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $window = $(window);
    $window.resize(function () {
        if ($window.width() < 768) {
            if ($('#navul').hasClass('navbar-nav')) {
                $('#navul').removeClass('navbar-nav').addClass('nav-pills');
            }
        };
        if ($window.width() > 769) {
            if ($('#navul').hasClass('nav-pills')) {
                $('#navul').removeClass('nav-pills').addClass('navbar-nav');
            }
        };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: See the edit to my original question.  If you follow the link, the sample script works.  And I can replicate that on my page.  The problem seems to be with swapping out the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  $('#navul')
    .removeClass('navbar-nav nav-pills')
    .addClass(($(window).width() < 768 ) ? 'nav-pills' : 'navbar-nav');
});
```

Comment: See the edit to my original question.  If you follow the link, the sample script works.  And I can replicate that on my page.  The problem seems to be with swapping out the class.

Comment: Try to determine if it's a problem with the selector itself. For example run from browser's console something like: $('#navul').attr('test', 'worked'). If this is not working, i guess you might have a duplicated id.